# CoreMotion attitude affected by linear motion

Tags: ios, gyroscope

I'm developing an app that has to use very small changes in gyroscope data.

The problem is that while keeping the device flat on the table and accelerating it horizontally, CoreMotion seems to also perceive that linear acceleration as angular acceleration.

The pitch and roll values, coming directly from deviceMotion, change with a maximum amount of 3 degrees and come back to the default value while decelerating.
I would have expected only one angle (yaw) to change since you can rotate the device that way while keeping it horizontal.
It does not matter which reference attitude I use.

The same issue seems to affect the quaternion of deviceMotion.attitude. At first I thought this was an effect of the sensor fusion algorithm used in CoreMotion, but rotationRate coming from CMGyroData (which should be raw data) changes aswel.

Has anyone noticed this problem before?